# How do I do a block search-and-replace with Vim?

Tags: vim, regex

I have text in Vim

1. hit `Ctrl+V` to put VIm in block mode
2. highlight the text I want
3. type `:` this gives the this prompt `:'<,'>`
4. I add to the prompt my regex `s/ /*/g`. This leaves me with `:'<,'>s/ /*/g` and the text highlighted
5. I hit enter

Unfortunately, it operates on the whole line for the block, not just the block. Is there anyway to do a block search and replace?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using ex commands in visual block mode, `:`, they always operate on the whole line.  There are two ways around this:

1. The `\%V` atom will match only inside the visual area. Try

   ```
   :'<,'>s/\%V /*/g
   ```

   See `:help %V`
2. There are special visual versions of some commands, live v_s or v_r.  See `:help visual-operators`

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this to work

Comment: the \%V atom will restrict a pattern so that it matches only inside the visual selection.  Try `:'<,'>s/\%V /*/g`

Comment: This page has a good writeup on what you are trying to do. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection